# Rename command not evaluating expressions

Tags: shell, unix

i have the  following files in my unix box:

```
CB_CB13_B01_20190502.txt 

CB_CB13_B01_20190503.txt.1

CB_CB13_B01_20190504.txt.2 

CB_CB13_B01_20190505.txt.3

CB_CB13_B01_20190506.txt.a 

CB_CB13_B01_20190507.txt.b
```

and so on

I am trying to remove all of the characters after .txt with the help of rename command:

```
rename "txt.*" ".txt" *
```

The rename is not working when i use * in the expression. any idea what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

`rename` uses [Perl Compatible Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) for substitution, e.g. `s/txt.*/txt/`

So, try this:

```sh
rename 's/txt.*/txt/' *
```

**Note**: you may use `-n` switch to just try without real renaming.

```sh
$ rename -n 's/txt.*/txt/' *
> rename(B_CB13_B01_20190503.txt.1, B_CB13_B01_20190503.txt)
> rename(B_CB13_B01_20190504.txt.2, B_CB13_B01_20190504.txt)
> rename(B_CB13_B01_20190505.txt.3, B_CB13_B01_20190505.txt)
> rename(B_CB13_B01_20190506.txt.a, B_CB13_B01_20190506.txt)
> rename(B_CB13_B01_20190507.txt.b, B_CB13_B01_20190507.txt)
```

Comment: sorry . it didnt work as well. i tried in both bash and ksh.

Comment: Typo maybe?   `touch CB_CB13_B01_20190504.txt.2 && ls && rename -v 's/txt.*/txt/' *  && ls`

Comment: @jdw i tried yours as well and its not working. is there a version of rename that i have to invoke?

Comment: "not working" not conclusive.  What was the error message?

Comment: bash-4.2$ rename -v 's/txt.*/txt/' *
bash-4.2$ ls -ltr

Comment: There are **two** `rename` commands in general use by Linux distros. Perl `rename` that supports REs and `rename` provided by the `util-linux` package that does not. `man 1 rename` to confirm which version you have.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks. this is my issue. the rename in my server is from util-linux and after installing perl rename. my original command itself worked. Thanks a ton and it ended my 7 hour long search

Answer (score 1):

@Yasen was right:

Test:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f something.txt
touch something.txt.2
echo "original contents:"
ls something*
rename --version
rename -v 's/txt.*/txt/' something*
echo "updated contents:"
ls something*
```

Result

```
original contents:
something.txt.2
/usr/bin/rename using File::Rename version 0.20

something.txt.2 renamed as something.txt
updated contents:
something.txt
```